# XSL:FO horizontal formatting, new line if doesn't fit

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have multiple blocks in my xsl file, which I want to be formatted in one line, but in case there's not enough space - blocks would move to the next line. 
Currently I have the following xsl block:

```
  <fo:static-content flow-name="header-continued">
   <fo:block-container>
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:for-each select="/myroot/category">
       <fo:inline>
         <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
       </fo:inline>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:block>
   </fo:static-content>
  </fo:block-container>
```

Currently in case there's not enough width - content just gets cut on the left and right sides. 
Behavior I want is similar to HTML markup when there're several DIVs and they have display:inline-block style.

Comment: There's something that you're not telling us: `wrap-option="wrap"` is the default anyway, and that allows line breaking.  It sounds like your text is centered and that you are using other properties to keep text on one line.  Is there more information that you can provide?

Comment: Hi @TonyGraham, I've updated xsl block in the question and tried to remove wrap-option at all - it doesn't affect the result - all the category names are in one line and in case there're too many - they get cut on the right side.

Comment: I know that there're some html -> xsl:fo converters and probably I can try to convert html version of markup I want to xsl:fo, but currently I'm struggling to make those converters working

Comment: Your XSLT excerpt is currently not well-formed XML: the last two tags are start tags, not end tags.  Also, it doesn't show why your content would stay on one line. Are you setting `keep-together`, `keep-together.within-line`, or `white-space-treatment` anywhere?

Comment: Use fo:float with float left and they will stack and break. Or end the inline with a zero-width breaking space.

Comment: @TonyGraham, I fixed the xml, it's actually a bit simplified version of what I have, but it has all the key tags. I'm new to xsl:fo but I thought 'inline' tag allows my content to stay in line and it does - if I remove it and change it to fo:block - all the content goes in one column. I'm not using keep-together or others attributes you mentioned

Comment: @KevinBrown: FOP 1.1 doesn't support `fo:float` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some formatters when given this:

```
<fo:inline>foo</fo:inline><fo:inline>foo</fo:inline><fo:inline>foo</fo:inline><fo:inline>foo</fo:inline><fo:inline>foo</fo:inline>
```

will not break between each of the  elements. Thus, change your template to output a breaking space in between each `<fo:inline>`.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space

The entity is `&#8203;`

Like:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="/myroot/category">
   <fo:inline>
     <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
   </fo:inline>
   <xsl:text>&#8203;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

This should create a zero-width breaking space between each `<fo:inline>` to allow it to break for multiple lines.

This assumes of course you want no space in between them.

Now, that said, in the above template I would note that the `<fo:inline>` elements do absolutely nothing (except possibly cause the issue you have) as they carry no separate styles or anything.

I would assume you would be happy with:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="/myroot/category">
     <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Which in reality is exactly the same. And if your data looks like this:

```
<name>foo</name>
<name>bar</name>
<name>foo</name>
<name>bar</name>
<name>foo</name>
<name>bar</name>
```

Then your output would be:

foobarfoobarfoobar

And then you can see why there are no breaks.

Comment: Kevin, thank you a lot! I'm wondering weather you know if it's possible to 'justlfy' all those inline elements, I tried text-align=justify but it didn't work. I'll probably need to create a separate question but anyway, you saved me A LOT of time, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `fo:inline` to an `fo:inline-container` that contains an `fo:block` that contains the name.

The `fo:inline-container` will take as much width as it needs (unless you specify a width) and the text inside it will not break over a line (unless it is wider than the available width).  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_inline-container.

---

Alternatively, change `<fo:inline>` to `<fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">`.  That should work with FOP 1.1.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use inline-container because I use Apache FOP 1.1 which doesn't support this tag. I'll try to figure out whether it's possible to migrate project to newer fop version, but I doubt :(

Comment: There are, of course, other formatters that fully implement `fo:inline-container`, but the alternative solution should work with FOP 1.1.

Comment: I've tried alternative solution but unfortunately got the same result - category names are rendered from left side but on the right side they get cut instead of moving to the new line :(

Comment: You might need the second suggestion by @kevinbrown: inside the `xsl:for-each`, add `<xsl:text>&#x2008;</xsl:text>` after the `fo:inline` to add a zero-width space between each `fo:inline`.  That should give FOP a place to break without it being obvious to the reader.